# Solicitud de servicio repetido con options

Tags: c#, angularjs, http

El código realiza la solicitud al servicio una sola vez:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] sin embargo el servicio es llamado dos veces por la página WEB, la primera vez con Request Method: OPTIONS (con respuesta vacía) y la segunda vez con Request Method: GET (con la respuesta del servicio);[image: Solicitud de servicios]

Por qué se realiza dos veces la consulta? Depende de la sicronía? Se requiere que solo se ejecute una vez.
El servicio es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Es muy importante que escribas el codigo en texto, y no con imagenes

Comment: Podrias confirmar que tu servidor API esta en otro dominio o puerto o en un lugar distinto a quien hace el pedido? (la respuesta es que por cors hay un pre flight request, pero quiero confirmar eso)

Comment: El servidor del cual consume está en otro puerto! Y como se podria corregir?

Comment: Se corrige, pero depende de lo que mandes. hay todo un manual y depende de los pedidos, que no especificaste en tu pregunta (como son las llamadas a la api). Podrias arreglar la pregunta con lo que te pase en el primer comentario y agregar un ejemplo de la llamada que lanza el preflight?